# Swift SpriteKit　touchesBeganで行うNodeの対消滅

Tags: swift, xcode, spritekit

どなたか、よろしくお願いいたします！

missile（Node）をtouchesBeganで呼び出しています。
didBeginでmissile（Node）が接触したasteroid（Node）を消滅させる事が目的です。

問題なく、１度目のtouchesBeganは作動して、missile（Node）が発射されるのですが、２度目以降のtouchesBeganが作動しません。原因がわからず大変困っております。

また、上記のご回答のみで十分なのですが、もう一つ解決して頂きたい問題がございますので、もしお分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授くださいませ。

touchesBegan内でmissile（Node）の発射を宣言しており、その発射間隔を今回は0.2秒に設定しております。
この状態で実行すると、0.2秒間以内に２回以上のタッチをするとエラーが出てしまいます。
こちらも原因が不明でございます。

どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var spaceship:SKSpriteNode! = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spaceship") 
    var button : SKSpriteNode! 
    var missile: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "missile") 

    let spaceshipCategory : UInt32 = 0b0001
    let missileCategory : UInt32 = 0b0010
    let asteroidCategory  : UInt32 = 0b0100

    var timar: Timer?

    func DegreeToRadian(Degree : Double!) -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat(Degree) / CGFloat(180.0 * M_1_PI)
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black 

        self.spaceship.alpha = 1 
        self.spaceship.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / -2 + 100, y: view.frame.height / -2 + 100) 
        self.spaceship.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150) 
        self.spaceship.zRotation = DegreeToRadian(Degree: 0) 
        self.spaceship.isUserInteractionEnabled = false 
        self.spaceship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.spaceship.frame.width * 0.1) 
        self.spaceship.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = spaceshipCategory
        self.spaceship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory | asteroidCategory
        self.spaceship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = asteroidCategory
        self.addChild(self.spaceship) //宇宙船didMove


        self.button = self.childNode(withName: "button") as? SKSpriteNode 
        if let button = self.button {
            button.name = "button" 
            button.alpha = 0.0 
            button.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2.0)) 

        }


        timar = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            self.addasteroid()
        })

          }


    //ここでmissile（Node）を宣言しbutton（Node）をタップした際に実行されるようにしてます。このコードは正常に作動するようです。
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isPaused { return }

        self.missile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.missile.frame.height / 2 ) 
        self.missile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = missileCategory
        self.missile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory | asteroidCategory
        self.missile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = asteroidCategory


        if let touch = touches.first { 
            let locatin = touch.location(in: self) 
                if self.atPoint(locatin).name == "button" { 

                   missile.position = CGPoint(x: self.spaceship.position.x , y: self.spaceship.position.y + 10 ) 
                   missile.size = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75) 
                   addChild(missile) 


                    let topButton = SKAction.moveTo(y: frame.width / 2 - self.spaceship.position.y , duration: 0.2) 
                        let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent() 
                        missile.run(SKAction.sequence([topButton, remove])) 

              }
          }
      }**

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first 
        let buttonLocation = touch?.location(in: self)  
        switch self.atPoint(buttonLocation!).name == "button" { 
        case true:
            break

        default:
            let location = touches.first!.location(in: self) 
            let action = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y:location.y + 20), duration: 0.1) 
            spaceship.run(action) 
        }

        }


    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    }


    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    }


    func addasteroid() {

        let names = ["asteroid1","asteroid2","asteroid3"]
        let index = Int.random(in: 0...2) 
        let name = names[index] 
        let asteroid = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: name) 

        let XHighest: CGFloat = self.frame.width / 2 - spaceship.size.width 
        let XLowest: CGFloat = self.frame.width / -2 + spaceship.size.width 
        let random = CGFloat.random(in: XLowest...XHighest) /
        asteroid.position = CGPoint(x: random, y: frame.width) 
        asteroid.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) 

        asteroid.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: asteroid.frame.width)
        asteroid.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = asteroidCategory
        asteroid.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory | asteroidCategory
        asteroid.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory

        addChild(asteroid) 

        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: frame.width / -2 - 100, duration: 1.0) 
        let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        asteroid.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]))
    }

//ここからのコードが微妙です。
        func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

            var asteroid: SKPhysicsBody
            var target: SKPhysicsBody

            if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == asteroidCategory {
                asteroid = contact.bodyA
                target = contact.bodyB

            } else {
                asteroid = contact.bodyB
                target = contact.bodyA
            }

            guard let asteroidNode = asteroid.node else { return }
            guard let tagetNode = target.node else { return }
            guard let Bakuhatu = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Bakuhatu") else { return }
            Bakuhatu.position = asteroidNode.position
            addChild(Bakuhatu)

            //asteroid（Node）の接触先がmissile（Node）だった場合にasteroid（Node）とmissile（Node）を消滅させたいです。１度目のタップは正常なのですが、１度このアクションを実行すると２度目以降が作動しなくなってしまいます。。
            asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
            if target.categoryBitMask == missileCategory  {
                tagetNode.removeFromParent()
            }

            self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)) {
                Bakuhatu.removeFromParent()
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: ソースコード内で `**` での強調をしようとしている箇所がありますが、正しく表示されないので別途説明用のコメントを (コード内に) 追記するか、必要なら該当箇所のみ抜き出して質問の本文で説明する形をおすすめします。

Comment: ご提示のコードをXcodeで新規作成したプロジェクトにコピーしてみましたが、種々のエラーが出てビルドできませんでした。おそらくもともとのコードから、ご質問とは関係の薄い箇所を削り落としてのコードだと思われ、あちこち手を入れて、ビルドできるまで持って行きましたが、それでもダメでした。asteroidとmissileが同じ方向、つまり平行に動くので、永遠衝突することがありません。明らかに、ご提示のコードをビルドして動かしたことがまったくないことがわかります。「手抜き」が悪いことだとは言いません。すくない手間で、効率を上げることは、とても大事なことです。しかし、手を抜いたことで、逆に効率が下がる、今回の場合、問題解決から遠ざかってしまうことは、本末転倒と言わなければいけません。質問者さんには、最も効率をあげることを目標にして、質問文と、コードに修正を加えていただくことを、質問者さん自身の利益のために、求めます。

Comment: nagonsoftware さんありがとうございます。
私が質の低いご質問をしてしまったが為に、ご迷惑をおかけいたしました。。
お陰様でこちらの問題は自己解決する事ができました。
親身にアドバイス頂きましてありがとうございます。
引き続きよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: cubickさん。ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正いたしました。